suddenly my maui application is not run on android on debug with zero code change
i didn't change the code for 2 month - and all work perfectly.
i update the visutl studio 2022 - and i runing my application on debug mode - and its hang
the error that i get is
[Gralloc4] mapper 4.x is not supported
[OpenGLRenderer] Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
[0:] ********************************** UNHANDLED EXCEPTION! Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer'.
when i run my application as 'start without debugging' its run ok - and i don't see this error on the output.
anyone had this problem ?
how solve this ?

Due to the update of the Visual Studio, you can clean the bin and obj file of the project and rebuild it.

@GuangyuBai-MSFT this is first thing you do on update to delete bin@obj - and rebuild - and on my case this not solve anything. usually on android studio this happened - but this time in on VS2022 - this break all my project
